# Visual Studio 2022 how to debug native C/C++ library (generated with gcc gnu compiler) from NET 6 C# multi-platform console application

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

What must be configured in Visual Studio 2022 to be able to debug (step into) the calls to a C/C++ native library (generated with gcc gnu compiler, with the help of the CMake c++ template project), from the main NET 6 C# multi-platform console application that loads/uses the native library? The functions from the native library are declared with DllImport in the console app.
I cannot figure out how to configure Visual Studio 2022 to use the .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) for the console application and the gdb debugger (for Windows - mingw, and for WSL/Ubuntu) when stepping into the native library function calls.
This is the sample code, I would like to step into the MyTest() function when debugging the NET 6 console app in Visual Studio 2022:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace LibTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string szDLL_Win_x64_Resource = @"C:\Code\Test\out\build\Mingw64-Debug\TestLib\TestLib.dll";
        private const string szDLL_Linux_x64_Resource = @"/home/xxx/.vs/Test/out/build/Linux-GCC-Debug/TestLib/TestLib.dll";

        [DllImport("TestLib.dll")]
        private static extern int MyTest(string strParam);

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string osKind = "Unknown";
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            {
                osKind = "Linux";
                // Load the Linux x64 DLL into the current process
                NativeLibrary.Load(szDLL_Linux_x64_Resource);
            }
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                osKind = "Windows";
                // Load the Windows x64 DLL into the current process
                NativeLibrary.Load(szDLL_Win_x64_Resource);
            }
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX)) { osKind = "MacOSX"; }

            string str = "abcdef";

            try
            {
                var res = MyTest(str);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code(with C++ .dll library), your requirement should be able to achieve.

Please follow the below steps:

1, Go to the Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General:

[image]

[image]

2, please unselect the following settings:

Just My Code

Require source file exactly match with original Version

Step over Properties and Operators

3, Right click your C# project, and then click properties; after that, go to the following place and select "enable native code debugging":

[image]

After the above steps, I am able to debug the logic of my CPP code.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me, it still steps over the call of the function from the DLL... Which compiler did you use for the generation of the C DLL (native library)?

Comment: It works! Just debug UE4 with its c# implementation.